# How to mock bean before ConfigDataLoader in SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

Config file processing has been [changed in Spring Boot 2.4](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4). It allows to eliminate bootstrap configuration and use `spring.config.import` instead together with some specific locations like `vault://…​`. Internally it uses `ConfigDataLocationResolver` and `ConfigDataLoader` from the `org.springframework.boot.context.config` package.

We are using Spring Cloud Vault to load secrets during service startup

*application.yml*

```
spring.config.import: vault://...
```

It works perfectly and allows to eliminate all complexity related to `bootstrap.yml` but not sure how to create integration tests using `SpringBootTest`. For Vault we need to mock `VaultTemplate` bean that is instantiated in [VaultConfigDataLoader](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/blob/main/spring-cloud-vault-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultConfigDataLoader.java#L197)

Currently we are using separate `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration` in `META-INF/spring.factories` to mock such beans but ideally we want to disable bootstrap completely and rely on a new config file lifecycle.

Are there any interceptors that allow to register mock bean before `ConfigDataLoader` without enabling bootstrap context?

Comment: You might want to look into disabling Vault integration during your test with a configuration property instead

Comment: Of course, we can disable it but the idea here is to validate vault configuration and make sure that secrets are loaded from the correct location.